# Redirect 404 to Home Page (NGINX / Cloudflare) Rule

Tags: nginx, redirect, cloudflare

I'm using nginx and cloudflare, how do I redirect all 404 pages to home page? I tried many ways but still not working. Please help me

this is my current settings on nginx

```
server {
    listen  80;
    listen  [::]:80;

    root    /var/www/html;
    index   index.html index.php;
    
    server_name  domain.com;
    access_log  off;
    error_log off;
    
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;

    location / {
    error_page 404 /;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /;
}
```

can someone tell me how to redirect properly with cloudflare or nginx?

Comment: Welcome to the community! What you have should work as it is. Have you restarted the server after your last modifications? Alternatively, you could use a named location like.. error_page 404 @notfound; and set a location block for this named block which return 302 /;

Comment: Also, the try_files directive is not needed in this particular case.

Comment: If you play with php, which you have not shown here, you must also add fastcgi_intercept_errors on; to your php block

Comment: Make sure to reload nginx (again) and clear cloudflare cache